# Unicenta POS can't connect to mysql 5.7 on Debian 11

Tags: mysql, debian, unicenta

Basically I can't get Unicenta opos to connect to a fresh install of mysql server on Debian 11. I have set up a user and granted privileges in mysql, created a new database named MAINDB and for some reason Unicenta won't make it connect....

a bit more info :

```
    mysql> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.36, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:          7
Current database:       MAINDB
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Cipher in use is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.7.36 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 10 min 16 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 19  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 106  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 99  Queries per second avg: 0.030
--------------
```

[unicenta config screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeJQj.png)

[unicenta error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhT9p.png)

Any ideas?

OS info (hostnamectl):
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Kernel: Linux 5.10.0-8-amd64
Architecture: x86-64

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR unipos;
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'unipos' on host '%'
mysql> select host from mysql.user
    -> ;
+-----------+
| host      |
+-----------+
| localhost |
| localhost |
| localhost |
| localhost |
+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I also had run the

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES * . * ON 'unipos'@'localhost';
```

and

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

after creating the unipos user.

This is the error message returned by Unicenta :

> com.openbravo.basic.BasicException:  Unable to
> connect to your Database Server!
> Please check **User** and
> **Password** credentials are correct
> The User must exist on your
> Database Server
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
> Communications link failure
>
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 60
> milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
> 55 milliseconds ago.
>
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:  No appropriate protocol
> (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

UPDATE :

This is from the mysql's error log file, when trying to connect with Unicenta.

```
    Version: '5.7.36'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2021-11-09T16:39:31.970790Z 2 [Note] Bad handshake
2021-11-09T16:39:31.981642Z 3 [Note] Bad handshake
```

Comment: can you connect to the database using the mysql command line client using the unipos user?

Comment: @ysth, Yes. jr91@Luke-deb:~$ mysql -h localhost -u unipos -p MAINDB
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 53
Server version: 5.7.36 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: is it maybe using a different database when it tries to connect?  I see a blank Database dropdown.  is there a way to see the actual error it is getting?  The error you show seems like just a generic message

Comment: probably a silly question, but unicenta is running on the same server, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is a blank database.... and yes, they both run on the same machine.....

Comment: Error info updated.

Comment: Please share more details. Is this even related to programming?

Comment: No, it is not related to programming, more mysql setup.... Unicentaopos is an opensource POS system....

Comment: If this is not related to programming, this is off-topic here. Maybe serverfault.com is better suited

Comment: Oh, ok... well, I got my idea of asking in here because I have seen similar problems with Unicenta and mysql connectivity solved in here before. Unfortunately they do not solve my problem. Thank you for the guidance though.